# How to Fix Syntax Error CS1003 ',' expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am recreating Flappy bird as my first project in unity (version 2021.3.6f1). I'm using Visual Studio to compile the C# script.

I get error CS1003 ',' expected on (8,42)

My Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public FlightForce = new Vector2(0f, 10f);

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {

            rb.AddForce(FlightForce, ForceMode2D.Force);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `public FlightForce` should be `public Vector2 FlightForce` - you're missing the type. Fields must always have a type specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public FlightForce = new Vector2(0f, 10f); // <--- you didn't provide the type here

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {

            rb.AddForce(FlightForce, ForceMode2D.Force);

        }

    }
}
```